# FirebaseUIを利用したログイン実装について

Tags: swift, ios, firebase

FirebaseUIでログイン画面を実装してます。
Sing in with emailというボタンが表示されるはずなのですが、WelcomeというタイトルだけでUIは何も表示されません。

解決方法、ご存知でしたら教えて頂きたいです。
よろしくお願い致します。

**ソースコード**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseUI

class LogInViewController: UIViewController, FUIAuthDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var AuthButton: UIButton!

var authUI: FUIAuth { get { return FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()! }}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.authUI.delegate = self
    AuthButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.AuthButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@objc func AuthButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    let authViewController = self.authUI.authViewController()
    self.present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

public func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) {
    if error == nil {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTopView", sender: self)
    }
}

}
```

**画面表示**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [FUIEmailAuth()]
```

を追加すると上手く表示されました。

公式レファレンスには記載ありませんが、FirebaseUIに少し変更があったようです。